# What is Maven <parent> in Gradle?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gradle

On a maven project I have the tag:

```
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

What is Gradle's syntax for that?

This is my build.gradle currently. Im thinking this would need to be added on the build script, maybe replacing what I currently have. If possible, please explain why I would need to add it. I am trying to translate a pom.xml to gradle.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

/*Runtime dependencies*/
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.6.1")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.6.1")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
}
```

Comment: What do you want to inherit from the parent? Properties? Dependency Management? Common configuration? It's possible to declare all of this in a single place with Gradle, without needing inheritance.

Comment: I didn't need anything specific. I was more concerned that I would miss certain dependencies that `starter-parent` provided. My concern was due to a dependency not being met, but this turned out not to be the problem (which is fixed). However, John's response clears a big doubt I had.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Gradle you only have a parent->child relationship in a multi-module project. You do not have a child->parent definition as you have in Maven.

So you usually have a parent folder where you have a **settings.gradle** that contains the references to its children.

Like so (parent settings.gradle):

```
include 'sub-module-1'
include 'sub-module-2
```

Then you have two sub-folder *sub-module-1* and *sub-module-2* which contains their own build.gradle files.

But, coming back to your case, you don't need to have any of that when you are just using the spring-boot plugin *org.springframework.boot* plugin will configure all the necessary dependencies so you only need to add the optional dependencies you want.

Answer (score 8):

What is the equivalent of following `Gradle` parent syntax, in `Maven`

```
apply plugin : "io.spring.dependency-management"


dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:${springBootVersion}"
    }
}
```

Comment: This only imports managed dependencies, right? No properties.

Comment: this helped me a lot when trying to set spring boot parent of specific version for gradle project. Thanks